# Who are the persons (within the C of E) who are attempting to depart from calling God 'He'?

Tags: bishops, church-of-england, synodal-path

The 'Church of England' is 'considering' whether to stop referring to God as 'he' says an article today published by [ITV.com](https://www.itv.com/news/2023-02-07/church-of-england-considering-whether-to-stop-referring-to-god-as-he).

'The Church' is to launch a 'new project' apparently.

> Any potential alterations, which would mark ***a departure from traditional Jewish and Christian teachings dating back millennia*** , would have to be approved by synod, the Church’s decision-making body.

The Rt Rev Dr Michael Ipgrave, Bishop of Lichfield and vice-chair of the liturgical commission responsible for the matter, said the Church had been “exploring the use of gendered language in relation to God for several years”.

Again, the Bishop of Lichfield says 'the Church has been exploring'.

Who are the actual people who are supporting, advising, and actively attempting to push through such language alterations ?

Who publicly admits to being involved, apart from Michael Ipgrave ?

Comment: @AmatsukiLove The question does not discuss the issue nor did I ask for such discussion. I asked as to _what persons were responsible_ for the issue being raised and pushed forward. The tags all relate to the C of E not the details of the issue. I am not looking for an opinionated discussion of said issue.

Comment: understood; I'm sorry. But also: "Any clod can have the facts, but having opinions is an art." - Doron Zeilberger

Comment: @AmatsukiLove Opinions are off-topic on SE-C. And also throughout Stack Exchange. The archives are for factual and academic research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Church of England Liturgical Commission is chaired by the Bishop of Exeter and the Bishop of Lichfield is Vice-Chair.  The other members of the Commission are:

> Ms Shayne Ardron

> The Revd Dr Andrew Atherstone

> The Revd Philip Barnes

> The Revd Mark Earey

> Ms Kashmir Garton

> The Revd Canon Dr Christopher Irvine

> The Revd Canon Dr Simon Jones

> Mr Simon Kershaw

> The Revd George Lane

> The Revd Fiona Mayer-Jones

> Mrs Lucy Moore

> Dr Bridget Nichols

> The Revd Canon Dr Jo Spreadbury

> The Revd Canon Dr Samuel Wells

> The Revd Dr Jennifer Strawbridge

> National Liturgy and Worship Adviser - Dr Matthew Salisbury

> Administrative Secretary - Sue Moore

Source: https://www.churchofengland.org/about/leadership-and-governance/general-synod/commissions-and-committees#na

At the bottom of the link provided is an opportunity to make contact: If you have a question about any of our Committees, please get in touch using the Contact Form below. Please pick "General Enquiry" for the subject line.

I hope that helps!

P.S. At the bottom of the link above: “If you have a question about any of our Committees, please get in touch using the Contact Form below. Please pick "General Enquiry" for the subject line.”

Comment: Thank you. Accepted. Good to know who these people are.